Stripe integration on iOS, Android, and web(on Chrome and Safari on iOS and Windows)
I am trying to integrate Strip payments into my Flutter app on Android, iOS, and web. On the web, I need it to work on any browser and on any OS.
I have looked at some YouTube videos but I still can't get web to work. I even hired a guy from Upwork and he gave a solution but his solution killed my iOS and Android solutions.
I have it working on Android and iOS but I am having trouble getting it to work on the web.
Here is my code for Stripe:
class StripePaymentScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final String email;
  final String password;

  const StripePaymentScreen(this.email, this.password, {super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<StripePaymentScreen> createState() =>
      _StripePaymentScreenState();
}

class _StripePaymentScreenState extends ConsumerState<StripePaymentScreen> {
  Map<String, dynamic>? paymentIntent;
  bool showSpinner = false;
  bool registrationFail = false;
  String errorMessage = "";
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Subscription Payment'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('Monthly subscription is 15.00 USD'),
            TextButton(
                child: const Text('Subscribe Now!'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await makePayment();

                  /// Register the new user
                  try {
                    final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: widget.email, password: widget.password);
                    if (newUser != null) {
                      ref
                          .read(usersNotifierProvider.notifier)
                          .updateuserID(newUser.user!.uid);

                      ref
                          .read(usersNotifierProvider.notifier)
                          .updateEmail(newUser.user!.email!);
                      ref
                          .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                          .updatenewUser(true);
                      ref
                          .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                          .updatenewCompany(true);

                      /// Send the email verification
                      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const VerifyEmailScreen()));
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        registrationFail = true;
                      });
                    }
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = false;
                    });
                  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                    switch (error.code) {
                      case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                      case "invalid-email":
                        errorMessage =
                            "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
                        break;
                      case "email-already-in-use":
                        errorMessage = "Email is already in use.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                      case "wrong-password":
                        errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
                        break;
                      case "weak-password":
                        errorMessage = "Weak password";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                      case "user-not-found":
                        errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                      case "user-disabled":
                        errorMessage =
                            "User with this email has been disabled.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
                      case "too-many-requests":
                        errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
                      case "operation-not-allowed":
                        errorMessage =
                            "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
                        break;
                      default:
                        errorMessage =
                            "An undefined Error happened. Please try again.";
                    }

                    if (errorMessage != "") {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar((SnackBar(
                        content: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            errorMessage,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                          ),
                        ),
                        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
                          left: 10,
                          right: 10,
                        ),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                      )));
                    }
                  }
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> makePayment() async {
    try {
      // Create payment intent data
      paymentIntent = await createPaymentIntent('15', 'USD');
      // initialise the payment sheet setup
      await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          // Client secret key from payment data
          paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent!['client_secret'],
          googlePay: const PaymentSheetGooglePay(
              // Currency and country code is accourding to India
              testEnv: true,
              currencyCode: "USD",
              merchantCountryCode: "US"),
          // Merchant Name
          merchantDisplayName: 'Deal Diligence',
          // return URl if you want to add
          // returnURL: 'flutterstripe://redirect',
        ),
      );
      // Display payment sheet
      displayPaymentSheet();
    } catch (e) {
      print("exception $e");

      if (e is StripeConfigException) {
        print("Stripe exception ${e.message}");
      } else {
        print("exception $e");
      }
    }
  }

  displayPaymentSheet() async {
    try {
      // "Display payment sheet";
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
      // Show when payment is done
      // Displaying snackbar for it
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text("Paid successfully")),
      );
      paymentIntent = null;
    } on StripeException catch (e) {
      // If any error comes during payment
      // so payment will be cancelled
      print('Error: $e');

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text(" Payment Cancelled")),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error in displaying");
      print('$e');
    }
  }

  createPaymentIntent(String amount, String currency) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> body = {
        'amount': ((int.parse(amount)) * 100).toString(),
        'currency': currency,
        'payment_method_types[]': 'card',
      };
      var secretKey = dotenv.env["STRIPE_SECRET"];
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents'),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $secretKey',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: body,
      );
      print('Payment Intent Body: ${response.body.toString()}');
      return jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    } catch (err) {
      print('Error charging user: ${err.toString()}');
    }
  }
}

How do I get web to work?
Thanks

You didn't share any errors or explained what is and isn't working or which docs you are following. You should likely talk directly to the developers of the SDK you are using for Flutter since Stripe doesn't have one. Otherwise try using https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe

Thanks for your response. I am not getting any errors, Stripe just doesn't come up on the web.

Unfortunately this is not something that can be debugged without more details. I'd recommend contacting the developers of that SDK if you use it and otherwise contact Stripe support directly: https://support.stripe.com/contact
